# Build array from nodes from RSS where keys contain colons

Tags: templating, array

Probably pure twig:

I am building an array from nodes taken from a RSS-feed where one of the keys contains a colon which of course breaks everything. Like so:

Node in feed:

```
<media:thumbnail url="stuff I like to get." />
```

My twig:

```
{% for node in feed %}
        {% set latestArticles = latestArticles|merge([{
                'timestamp': node.pubDate|atom,
                'title': node.title,
                'uri': node.link,
                'description': node.description,
                'thumbnail' : node.media:thumbnail,
            }]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

So how do I get `media:thumbnail`?

I have tried different things but without luck.

Comment: Have you tried _brackets notation_, i.e. `node['media:thumbnail']`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It says:

`Key "media:thumbnail" for array with keys "title, link, pubDate, category, guid, description, dc:creator" does not exist.`

Comment: That suggests that the structure of the node object isn’t what you think it is. Try enabling devMode and do {{ dump(node) }} to see the object’s contents and structure

Comment: Haven’t thought about dump. 

No idea, why. You’re right, it’s an array. So the correct code is: `'img' : node['media:content'][1]['@url']`

Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusScheller would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Comment: That is the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mats-mikkel-rummelhoff suggested, that data type is an array. So I was able to get the desired value by using:

```
'img' : node['media:content'][1]['@url']
```

Thanks, Mats.